# MySQLi with real_escape_string not working with brackets

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a textbox which inserts a new row into the database.

The issue is that if the user inputs a bracket "(" or ")", it doesn't insert the row.

I have tried using `$link->real_escape_string($value)` but that only seems to fix the issue with apostrophes.

Is there another to use with brackets?

Thanks!

EDIT: The code:

```
foreach($_POST as $name => $value) {
    if(0 === strpos($name, "amenities")){
        //print "$name : $value<br>";
        $query = "INSERT into content (`type`, `value`, `additional`) VALUES ('amenities', '" .$link->real_escape_string($value) . "', '')" or die("Error in the consult.." . mysqli_error($link)); 
        $result = mysqli_query($link, $query); 
    }
}
```

Comment: If you use mysqli's prepared statements you won't have to escape anything :)

Comment: Please, post the code related to the POST and reception of your data.

Comment: @Begueradj Posted the code above. All the other POST requests work fine, but it ignores any that have brackets.

Comment: @MRC I tested your code using `(hello)` and `("hello")` entered in a form input and it worked perfectly well. Something else is causing this. What is the column's type and length for the `value` column? Plus, it's probably your conditional statement causing this. Try and remove it and use it as a single entry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you got the `space` in your value try this solution

```
$query = "INSERT into content (`type`, `value`, `additional`) VALUES ('amenities', '".mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$value)."', '')" or die("Error in the consult.." . mysqli_error($link));
```

Comment: Tried your new answer but no luck. Gives error about only having one parameter, I added the other but still doesn't work.

Comment: @Arif_suhail_123 You should always make the edit in your answer to reflect the comment you made. I have made the edit for it. ;)

Comment: @Arif_suhail_123 Thanks bro. Btw, I tested OP's code, and there's nothing wrong with it. So, something else is causing this.

Comment: @Arif_suhail_123 My guess is that it's the `foreach` loop causing the problem.

Comment: @Arif_suhail_123 That could also be a factor. And/or the form element already contains a space. Best to use `trim()`.

Comment: @Arif_suhail_123 I can't see how that would cause problems, since I tested with ampersands and quotes, including brackets. OP is not telling us something and most likely is leaving something out, or has not responded any further because he/she found the errors of his/her ways.

Comment: @Arif_suhail_123 Many times OP's either don't care to respond or just left for dinner lol - Oh well, we do our best and that's all we can do.

Comment: @Arif_suhail_123 I was unable to reproduce, so I voted to close as *"This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error."* - I have tried OP's code, your code, my code and all were successfull. This `"Flat screens TV’s over 40 cable channels (good selection & sports)"` is what I used, even variants of without quotes, with and without prepared statements. As far as I'm concerned, I think this matter is closed. The only other thing I can think of is that OP's column type and/or length may be incorrect. *Cheers*

Answer (score 0):

Try instead of
`$link->real_escape_string($value)`

doing something like:

`mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $value)`

Comment: Hmm thanks that works. I'm confused as I checked several questions about this but they said to use it the other way.

Comment: Actually sorry that didnt work. IT worked when I added "()" to the end of a string, but it didnt work for this string: "Flat screens TV’s over 40 cable channels (good selection & sports)"

Answer (score 0):

use mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $value) or just {}... see an exemple:

< ?php
 $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user='{$_POST['username']}' AND password='{$_POST['password']}'";

mysqli_query($query);

echo $query;

"SELECT * FROM users WHERE user='aidan' AND password='' OR ''=''"
?>

Comment: Hi, I have tried using the {} around the varible, I can see it's easier but it still is not inserting the row.